# Identfying SQL Server NULL in Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Below is code snippet from Powershell

```
$query =  "select MAX(convert(varchar(10),server_time,102))from status_history where status not like ('ERROR FETCHING%')" 
$servers = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -query $query -ServerInstance "100.81.60.2" -Database "temp" -Username "temp" -password "temp"
```

I need to check in Powershell if the sql query contained in `$query` returns `NULL`.
I tried using

```
if($servers.Column1 -eq NULL)
```

but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: try using `if($servers.Column1 -eq $null)` or just omit it: `if ($servers.Column1)`

Comment: Using `if ($servers.Column1)` is not a good idea in this context, because values like 0 or "" (empty string) also evaluate to `$false`. I'd try [`[DBNull]::Value.Equals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22287263/1630171).

Answer (score 2):

Compare the result to [`[DBNull]::Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if ([DBNull]::Value.Equals($server.Column1)) {
  ...
}
```

If `$server.Column1` contains more than one value you may need to check each value individually.