# Calling stored procedure that requires parameter with NULL value

Tags: powershell

I’m working with a stored procedure from a vendor, so I can’t update the procedure. The call I’m making requires a few parameters be passed as NULL. I’m using:

```
$sqlConnection = OpenConnection
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
### Stored Procedure Name
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "procedure.name"
### Stored Procedure Parameters
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", "SomeValue") | Out-Null
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", DBNull.Value) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Null in PowerShell is represented by `$null`

Comment: So what happens when you try this? do you get an error? Everything in this post uses `[System.DBNull]::Value` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285149/dealing-with-system-dbnull-in-powershell

Comment: @Daniel when I try $null i get an exception error saying the function expects parameter '@param2', which was not supplied.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid using DBNull.value just gave me an error saying there was a missing expression after the comma. But using the [System.DBNull]::Value worked. Thank you so much. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I can't take credit for my googling. If you don't mind I will mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with System.DBNull in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285149/dealing-with-system-dbnull-in-powershell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Insert from Powershell: null values inserted as "blank"](/q/9507669/90527)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that did fix it. Please go ahead and mark it as duplicate. Thank you. I thought I updated this a few days ago but it doesn't appear I saved the comment.